# docker-compose service cannot connect to mysql container in springboot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use the springboot service to connect to a mysql container,however it shows that i cannot connect to the database.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
dbmysql:
  container_name: dbmysql
  image: mysql:latest
  restart: unless-stopped  
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
    MYSQL_USER: "admin"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: freelance

  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/docker/volumes/freelance_volume/_data

userjob:
  depends_on:
    - dbmysql
    - eureka-server
  image: userjob:latest
  container_name: userjob
  build:
    context: userjob/.
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.layered #docker file path (. means current directory)
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  environment:
    - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://dbmysql:3306/freelance
    - spring.datasource.username=admin
    - spring.datasource.password="password"
    - log.level.root=debug
```

Yields :

```
error:
`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.18.0.10' (using password: YES) 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797671197Z   at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797672529Z   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797673778Z    at
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797674920Z    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797676415Z   at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797677642Z     at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797678805Z     at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797679943Z    at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na] 2023-02-22T17:36:09.797681125Z    at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.`
```

I have tried to set the port to the other eg.3307 or else and it all failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message indicates that the connection was successful, but the database account was rejected.

Looking at your MySQL container configuration, I see you are setting a password for the `root` user, but not for the `admin` user. You need to add the following environment variable to your MySQL container:

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
```

Comment: Thx so much .I have struggled for a long due to this small mistake